# how to know video start time is smaller than video duration in java-vlcj player

Tags: java, video, time, media, vlcj

I am trying to develop a video player application with java - vlcj player. I need to give random start time for bunch of videos. However some of videos are shorter than my random start time. I need to skip these videos and play next ones.

Here is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<videoCount;i++){
    int delay = playTime*1000; //milliseconds
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {


                videoPath = randomvVideoPath(directory); 


               //***  times[0] is start time, times[1] is stop time***//
               String[] times = startStop();


/*** I DONT KNOW IF THE START TIME IS SMALLER THAN THE VIDEO DURATION******/
 mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(videoPath,":start-time="+times[0], ":stop-time="+times[1]);

          }
      };
          new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}
```

How can I check this? getLength() and getTime() of  mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer() does not give the correct time.

Thanks in advance,,

Answer (score 0):

getLength() and getTime() *do* return the correct time, but sometimes this information is not available until *after* the media is playing. That's just how VLC works.

I would suggest instead looking at Java bindings for the native `MediaInfo` command-line utility and using that to get your video length.

Comment: i wrote this library a while ago to use MediaInfo to get just such information from the media file: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-info